# jquery ui slider last handle value when more sliders are present

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

How do I get back the first and last handle values from jquery ui range slider when more slider are present on the page. My actual code looks as it follows but the last value is going to take from the last slider last handle, I was trying to fix on id `#slider-range.ui-slider-handle:last` but did not work

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    step: 5,
    min: <?= $sel_minmax['price_min'] ?>,
    max: <?= $sel_minmax['price_max'] ?>,
    values: [<?= $params['price_min'] . ',' . $params['price_max'] ?>],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + ";" + ui.values[1]);

        $('.ui-slider-handle:first').html('<div class="tooltip top slider-tip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">' + ui.values[0] + '</div></div>');
        $('.ui-slider-handle:last').html('<div class="tooltip top slider-tip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">' + ui.values[1] + '</div></div>');
    }
});

$("#amount").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + ";" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
```

html

```
                <p>
                    <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="amount" />
                </p>
and other sliders..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    var valueArray = ui.values;
    valueArray.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
    valueArray[0]; // Farthest left value
    valueArray[valueArray.length-1]; //Farthest right value;
}
```